# How to unset numeric index elements from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a collection of array it contains both numeric index as well as non numeric. I want to unset all the numeric indexes.

My array is something like this .

```html
Array
(

    [554] => Array
        (
            [0] => 554
            [1] => Jiaqi Zheng
            [2] => Female
            [3] => 28
            [4] => Table Tennis
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [rank] => 554
            [athlet_name] => Jiaqi Zheng
            [gender] => Female
            [sport] => Table Tennis
        )

    [555] => Array
        (
            [0] => 555
            [1] => Zach Ziemek
            [2] => Male
            [3] => 23
            [4] => Athletics
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [rank] => 555
            [athlet_name] => Zach Ziemek
            [gender] => Male
            [sport] => Athletics
        )
)
```

Here i have to unset all the numeric index .

I used unset like this and its working fine for me .

```html
unset(
                     $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[     $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][0],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][1],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][2],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][3],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][4],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][5],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][6],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][7],
                      $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[$history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][8]
                      );
```

Is there any way I will reduce the lines of codes? here 0 to 8 are in one series.

Can I  unset all index in one line of code , as all are numeric?

Is it possible to use regular expression instead?

I want something like

```html
unset(
                     $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr[     $history_years_wise_country_wise_details_info[0]][anything_which_will_take_index_from_0_to_8]);
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `array_filter()` with `is_string()` function as its callback function:

```
$array = array_filter($array, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Comment: I am getting result like this .
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 
            [athlet_name] => 
            [gender] => 
            [sport] => 
        )

)

Comment: I tried your code .

$array = array();
  foreach($history_years_wise_country_wise_details_arr as $key2=> $hywcwda)
  {
   $array[] = array_filter($hywcwda, 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
  }
   echo '<pre>';print_r($array);exit;

Answer (score 2):

Use looping.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric ($key)) {
        unset($array [$key]);
    }
}
```

Or use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$filtered = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($key) {
        return !is_numeric($key);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 
            [athlet_name] => 
            [gender] => 
            [sport] => 
        )

)

I think it removed all the main keys .

Comment: Loop through main array and filter child elements. revo's answer is better one.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud used `foreach` loop with `is_numeric` function like

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_numeric($key)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

i think there is no need of any regular expression

Comment: again i have to use looping , is there any other way ? ,in same code i can not do it i guess

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `array` inside `array` first you need to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and then traverse through array using [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php),

considering `$array` as your `array`:

```
$resultData = array_map([$this, 'allData'], $array);

 public function allData($data)
 {
    $numericKeys = array_filter(array_keys($data), function ($k) {
        return is_int($k);
    });
    // Updated Code
    $arrayKeys = array_diff(array_keys($data),$numericKeys);
    return array_intersect_key($data,array_flip($arrayKeys));
 }
```

Comment: [554] => Array
        (
            [9] => rank
            [10] => athlet_name
            [11] => gender
            [12] => sport
        )

    [555] => Array
        (
            [9] => rank
            [10] => athlet_name
            [11] => gender
            [12] => sport
        )
removed numeric index but data is coming wrong.

Comment: I got the values .
 [554] => Array
        (
            [0] => 554
            [1] => Jiaqi Zheng
            [2] => Female
            [3] => Table Tennis
        )

    [555] => Array
        (
            [0] => 555
            [1] => Zach Ziemek
            [2] => Male
            [3] => Athletics
        )
I changed  return array_diff(array_keys($data),$numericKeys);   to

 return array_diff(array_values($data),$numericKeys);

Comment: I want associative array  only . here i am getting numeric index